# How to make a button clickable to another view controller only with textfield

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have this scenario that if the user clicks the button then another view controller will popuped which includes only a textView where the user can write something inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the the `.sheet` modifier to display a modal / popup like view in SwiftUI.

```
struct ContentDetail: View {
    struct Item {
        let uuid = UUID()
        let value: String
    }
    @State private var items = [Item]()
    @State private var show_modal = false
    var lectureName:String

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {
                        self.show_modal.toggle()
                    }, label: {
                        Text("✏️")
                            .font(.system(.largeTitle))
                            .frame(width: 77, height: 70)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                            .padding(.bottom, 7)

                    })
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .cornerRadius(38.5)
                        .padding()
                        .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.3),
                                radius: 5,
                                x: 3,
                                y: 3)
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: self.$show_modal) {
            CustomModalView()
        }
    }
}

struct CustomModalView: View {
    @State private var text = ""

    var body: some View {
        TextField("test", text: $text)
            .padding(5)
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            .font(.system(size: 60, design: .default))
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
    }
}
```

You can read more about it here: 
https://blog.appsbymw.com/posts/how-to-present-and-dismiss-a-modal-in-swiftui-155c/

Comment: is that posible to change the width and the height of the textField? or make it resizeble  to the users input?

Comment: You can replace TextField("Test", text: self.$text) in my example with any other SwiftUI view. 

The only important thing is that if you use an @EnvironmentObject and want to use it in your .sheet view, then you have to pas it down to the .sheet view like this:
TextField("Test", text: self.$text).environmentObject(eO)

Comment: could you please update your code? it did not work for me at all

Comment: I updated my code. Now using a custom View inside the .sheet. The TextField inside the View is styled to appear bigger.

Comment: the problem is now that the text inside the textfield is too large too. What is need is a big textfield with small text inside

Comment: I just added some basic code to show you how to change the view inside your .sheet. You can edit the view according to your wish.